# VB.NET equivalent to excel's quotient function

Tags: vb.net, excel

Does VB.NET have a function to get the quotient like you can in excel.

```
Quotient(12, 6)
```

Comment: Is this VBA or VB.NET? They are very different languages...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite what I wrote in the comment, for both of them the integer division is performed with the same operator, i.e. `\` (notice that it's not a regular slash, but a *back*slash).

```
5\2 => evaluates to an integer 2
5/2 => evaluates to a double 2.5
```

(notice that the return type here is for Integer operands, but it varies from the operands' type)

For more information on the VB.NET version of these operators see:

- [/ Operator (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25bswc76.aspx)
- [\ Operator (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e16fywh.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
quotient = 12 \ 6 ' filler filler filler
```

Answer (score 0):

In a case when there is no VBA equivalent, you can always use `WorksheetFunction`, for example:

```
WorksheetFunction.Quotient(Arg1, Arg2)
```